# How to build shell script for docker installation

Tags: shell-script, apt, docker, unattended-upgrades

I would like to create a bash file to automate a docker installation with following commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys <key>
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache policy docker-engine
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r) linux-image-extra-virtual
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
sudo service docker start
```

For me it is new, so I need a little advice. How can I handle commands which asks for confirmations?

Can I summarize both `apt-get install` lines?

Comment: If you're going to automate the process you need to identify which commands might ask for confirmation. Then you can check the man page for those commands to see if there's any way you can provide an answer (maybe a flag, or maybe it defaults to one particular course of action if there's no _stdin_ to read an answer from).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` takes `-y` (`--yes`/`--assume-yes`) option to take yes as the value for confirmation on such prompts, it's like pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> interactively.

So you can do:

```
apt-get install -y ...
```